# Reset Or Clear BootStrap validation messages ,when we open and close the pop-up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap Validation for the form .
This is working fine except one issue .

Without entering anything in the text , if clicked on Save , it displays **Validation** message , Click on Close button and 
relaunch the Modal , initially it displays **Validation** message

```
$('#taginsertform').bootstrapValidator(
{
        feedbackIcons:
        {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields:
        {
                recipientname:
                {
                        feedbackIcons: 'false',
                        validators:
                        {
                                notEmpty:
                                {
                                        message: 'Reciepnt Name cannot be empty'
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}).on('success.form.bv', function(e)
{
        e.preventDefault();
        addTagSbmt();
});
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/xmrxbL9f/74/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace event

```
shown.bs.modal
```

with

```
hide.bs.modal
```

so the validation errors get cleared while user is closing modal, not while openinig.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/51nbq3j3/)